# Who used the time leap machine, and is it relevant to the plot?

Tags: steins-gate

In *Steins;Gate Elite*, there is one point where Okabe comes back to the lab finding someone is using the time leap machine. However, I don't remember it being brought up again, so I wonder:

Who was using the time leap machine?

Did it have any significance to the plot or was it undone due to Okabe using the time leap machine as well?